Какие еще вы знаете виды схем данных, помимо Star- и Activity-Schema?
Кратко про проблему в общих словах:
Возникла необходимость реструктуризировать глобально (малой кровью навряд ли получится обойтись) схему данных. На данный момент - это очень хорошая Star схема, которая на текущий момент требует при определенных обстоятельствах включать и отключать некоторые связи, в зависимости от контекста, в котором я хочу получить представление данных. Всё это происходит в любимом power bi, и все было бы прекрасно, если бы нужная мне функция Row-Level Security работала с dax-межами, которые деактивируют и активируют связи.
К сути:
В поисках решения проблемы, я наткнулся на Activity Schem-у, которая объединяет множество Dimension и Fact таблиц в несколько перемерженных обджойниных гига-таблиц. На первый взгляд выглядит громоздко, неудобно, да и логичность схемы тоже теряется. Но из плюсов, неоспоримо, повышается производительность dax-меж и все связи по умолчанию становятся активными.
Стало интересно, есть ли у кого-то еще успешный опыт использования нестандартных схем?

очень хорошая Star схема, которая на текущий момент требует при определенных обстоятельствах включать и отключать некоторые связи, в зависимости от контекста, в котором я хочу получить представление данных Что за ерунда? Связи - это правила контроля целостности информации, и на отображение они не влияют от слова "никак".
